# "Migrations" hit an invalid opcode while deploying

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache

I have suddenly started getting '"Migrations" hit an invalid opcode while deploying' error when I do 'truffle deploy' command.

My migrations file has not changed so I'm not sure why I am suddenly getting this error. Everyone who's posted for the same error just suggests downloading latest versions of ganache/truffle but I have updated my truffle and ganache to the most up to date versions and still getting the error.

## This is the full error:
⠋ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
Starting migrations...

> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)

## 1_initial_migration.js

### ⠙ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
Deploying 'Migrations'

*** Deployment Failed ***st from solc-bin. Attempt #1

"Migrations" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:

- Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
- Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
- Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:

- Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
- Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
- Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

```
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:330:1
```

Truffle v5.9.2 (core: 5.9.2)
Node v18.7.0

Migrations.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Migrations {
    address public owner;
    uint256 public lastCompletedMigration;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Restricted to contract owner");
        _;
    }

    function setCompleted(uint256 completed) public restricted {
        lastCompletedMigration = completed;
    }

    function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
        Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
        upgraded.setCompleted(lastCompletedMigration);
    }
}
```

1_initial_migration.js

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

Comment: Hey there, I've just answered a very similar question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76411350/194982) ... looks like you've already resolved your issue, but there are the couple of other ways you can consider as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try change your pragma and solc version

Migrations.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
```

truffle-config.js

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.5.1"
}
```

Sometimes, solc works for me with 0.8.20 or 0.7.3

Comment: Yes that's solved the issue, thank you. my solc version was 0.8.20, weird that it just stopped working

Comment: Worked for me as well, but feels like a structurally wrong solution - rolling back to older version of compiler to make the deployment work. Also resulted in cascade of changes to satisfy older standards. Anyone managed to make it work with 0.8.20?

Comment: @IdoVanOrell same issue. I guess it's a stupid bug: seeing "0.8.20" as 0.8.2.

Answer (score 2):

Change solc version in the `truffle-config.js` file as below.

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.13"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading solc from 0.8.20 to 0.8.13 resolved the problem for me.

I got to that version by downloading the metacoin truffle box, verifying that migration works and then getting the version of solc from the truffle-config.js of the project.

It is worth doing the same, rather than using the specific solc version that resolved this for me at this point in time, as Truffle will probably update the metacoin box eventually to keep up with the rest of their tools and this number will get out of date.

Downloading the metacoin truffle box is as easy as this:

```bash
truffle unbox metacoin [PATH/TO/DIRECTORY]
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed all .sol contract version to fixed version, then the error disappeared.

pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using the latest version of ganache. Try installing ganache globally with  `npm install -g ganche` this should work

Answer (score 0):

Change compiler version 0.8.21 to 0.8.17 or lower in truffle-config.js file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34867994)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Solidity version 0.8.20 and above.
This is how I fixed [click here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150281/invalid-opcode-opcode-0x5f-not-defined/161747#161747)

Comment: please expand. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35804194)