# How do I fix 'Migrations hit an invalid opcode while deploying' error in Solidity?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, solidity

"Migrations" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:

- Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
- Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
- Adding reason strings to your assert statements.    getting this error how to solve

My migration.sol code

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

    //the version of solidity that is compatible

    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    contract Migrations {
      address public owner = msg.sender;
      uint public last_completed_migration;

      modifier restricted() {
        require(
          msg.sender == owner,
          "This function is restricted to the contract's owner"
        );
        _;
      }

      function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
        last_completed_migration = completed;
      }
    }
```

My truffle config.js file

```js
    const path = require("path");

    module.exports = {
      // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
      // to customize your Truffle configuration!
      contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "/build"),
  
   
      networks: {
        development: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" //Match any network id
     }
    },
    
    plugins: ["truffle-contract-size"],
    compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.8.0"
    }
    },
    solidity: {
    version: "0.8.3",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 1000,
      },
    },
  },
   };
```

Answer (score 6):

This is likely due to the recent introduction of a new opcode, `PUSH0`, as of `solc` version 0.8.20.

For a full list, see ["When did each opcode get added to the EVM?"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/150094/48984).

Essentially, your version of the solidity compiler is "ahead" of the network that you are attempting to deploy to. In other words, `solc` outputs bytecode that contains an opcode, but the network does not yet.

You have 3 potential solutions:

- Wait for your target network to support the new opcode, or use a different network.

  - Since your truffle config indicates that you are connecting to `127.0.0.1:8545`, this means that you can upgrade to the latest version of your network running locally (e.g. Ganache) and perhaps that will solve the problem
  - Downgrade to an earlier version of `solc`.
  - Change the `solc` version in your solidity files: `pragma solidity 0.8.19;`
- Change the `solc` version in your truffle config file: `version: "0.8.19"`

  - If the underlying cause of your error was indeed the `PUSH0` opcode, this will solve your problem as `solc` version 0.8.19 does not output this.
- Continue using the latest `solc` version, but specify a non-latest target EVM version

  - Update the `solc` section in your truffle config file to add a new property: `settings: { evmVersion: 'london' }`
  - Note that 0.8.20 targets `evmVersion: 'shanghai'` by default, which means it can output `PUSH0`
  - But if you override it to target `evmVersion: 'london'` instead, which is the 2nd most recent target EVM version (as of June 2023), you're essentially telling `solc` to **avoid** outputting `PUSH0`.
  - If the underlying cause of your error was indeed the `PUSH0` opcode, this will solve your problem as `solc` has been told not output this.

---

References:

- https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.8.20

> Assembler: Use `push0` for placing `0` on the stack for EVM versions starting from "Shanghai". This decreases the deployment and runtime costs.

- https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.20/using-the-compiler.html#setting-the-evm-version-to-target

> `solc --evm-version <VERSION> contract.sol`

- https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration/#solc

> `evmVersion: <string> // Default: "istanbul"`

Comment: I think this one's correct, before I used solidity version as ^0.8.0. After I changed it as 0.8.19, and it worked