# Migrations hit an invalid opcode while deploying

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js, truffle, opcode

When run truffle migration command it throws error, Tried many solutions but couldn,t corrected it.
PS C:\Users\Jatin\OneDrive - nsut.ac.in\Desktop\Truffle\web> truffle migration

## Compiling your contracts...

> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\demo.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\Jatin\OneDrive - nsut.ac.in\Desktop\Truffle\web\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:

- solc: 0.8.20+commit.a1b79de6.Emscripten.clang

## Starting migrations...

> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)

## 1_initial_migration copy.js

### Deploying 'Migrations'

*** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:

- Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
- Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
- Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:

- Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
- Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
- Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

```
at C:\Users\Jatin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\deployer\src\deployment.js:330:1
```

Truffle v5.9.3 (core: 5.9.3)
Node v18.16.0

I try many solutions to fix it but didn't solve it

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76411350/19062779

Answer (score 0):

We encountered similar issue in past. It is because of the new opcode `PUSH0` introduced in Solidity version 0.8.20.

By the way Truffle is now discontinued. To ensure smooth and secure development, I highly suggest switching to Hardhat.

Here is how you can configure your hardhat config:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.20",
    settings: {
      evmVersion: "paris"
    }
  }
};
```

Alternatively you can use Foundry which also good