# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode

Tags: exception, virtual-machine, solidity

1. Background
   When I walked through how to manually compile and deploy smart contract from the command line, to a local development blockchain. I had an issue when creating a web3 object which represents the HelloWorld contract instance deployed to our development environment.

```js
var helloWorldContract = eth.contract(helloWorldOpt.contracts["HelloWorld.sol:HelloWorld"].abi)
var helloWorldBin = "0x" + helloWorldOpt.contracts["HelloWorld.sol:HelloWorld"].bin

var deployTranObj = { from: eth.coinbase, data: helloWorldBin, gas: 3000000 }

var helloWordInstance = helloWorldContract.new(deployTranObj)
```

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at web3.js:6365:9(39)
    at send (web3.js:5099:62(29))
    at web3.js:3021:48(105)
    at <eval>:1:47(5)
```

The contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract HelloWorld {
    string public str = "Hello World!";

    function set(string memory s) public{
        str = s;
    }

    function get() public view returns(string memory) {
        return str;
    }

}
```

Successfully create the web3j instance. But return error:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at web3.js:6365:9(39)
    at send (web3.js:5099:62(29))
    at web3.js:3021:48(105)
    at <eval>:1:47(5)
```

Comment: Please use [formattin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 0):

An invalid opcode often arises due to incorrect binary data for contract deployment or a mismatch between the provided ABI and the actual contract.

1. Verify that your HelloWorld.sol file is correctly compiled.
2. Ensure `helloWorldOpt.contracts["HelloWorld.sol:HelloWorld"].abi` and `helloWorldOpt.contracts["HelloWorld.sol:HelloWorld"].bin` are accurate. Check the `HelloWorld.json` file in your build output folder for the correct ABI and bytecode.
3. Use a callback function with `new()` to get the instance after mining. e.g

```
helloWorldContract.new(deployTranObj, function(error, contract) {
    if (error) console.log("Error: " + error);
    else if (contract.address) console.log("Contract mined, address: " + contract.address);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything inherently problematic with your smart contract code.

In your deployment deployment script, feels like there should some `await`s on promises, or a callback (as [suggested by Hassan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76774314/194982)).

That being said, the problem is most likely a mismatch between the version the bytecode output by `solc` and the version of the bytecode supported by the EVM that you are deploying to.

Note that opcodes are not static, and they may be added or removed by means of EIPs (agreed upon by the Ethereum community). See the full list to date here: ["When did each opcode get added to the EVM?"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/150094/48984).

Your smart contract specifies this version of `solc`:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
```

... which means a wide range of versions can be used.
Narrow this down by specifying a specific version.
The latest version of `solc` which I consider to be production-ready is `0.8.17`,
and by that I mean supported by most developer tools, frameworks, etc.;
plus EVM implementations.

So change this statement to:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.17;
```

Next, install and use that version of `solc`, then compile your smart con tract with it:

```bash
npm install --global solc@0.8.17
solcjs --abi --bin HelloWorld.sol
```

Use your script to deploy this new output bytecode instead.

---

I've previously answered another similar question here,
which might be helpful to you in case the above does not work:
["How do I fix 'Migrations hit an invalid opcode while deploying' error in Solidity?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76411350/194982)

Answer (score 0):

To deploy contract manually you can try this script

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env" });
const jsonfile = require("jsonfile");

const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(process.env.PROVIDER);


const acc1 = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(process.env.PK!).address;

async function run() {
  const txCount = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(acc1);

  var data = jsonfile.readFileSync("build/contracts/ContractName.json").bytecode;


  const txObj = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(10000000),
    data: data,
  };

  const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
    txObj,
    process.env.PK
  );

  const result = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
  console.log(result);
}
```