# Truffle Migrate Error: "<ContractName>" hit an invalid opcode while deploying

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache

I'm trying to deploy a contract named `InfinityCanvas` on a local Ganache blockchain using Truffle. However, I'm encountering an "invalid opcode" error during the deployment process.

#### Issue:

When running `truffle migrate --reset`, I encounter the following error:

```
*** Deployment Failed ***

"InfinityCanvas" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.
```

#### Code Details:

1. **InfinityCanvas.sol**:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";

contract InfinityCanvas is ERC721Enumerable {
    // tokenId counter
    uint256 private _currentTokenId = 0;

    struct Canvas {
        string description;
        // Add other metadata attributes if needed
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Canvas) public canvases;

    constructor() ERC721("InfinityCanvas", "ICNV") {}

    function _getNextTokenId() private returns (uint256) {
        _currentTokenId += 1;
        return _currentTokenId;
    }

    function mintCanvas(address owner, string memory description) public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 newCanvasId = _getNextTokenId();
        _mint(owner, newCanvasId);
        canvases[newCanvasId] = Canvas(description);
        return newCanvasId;
    }
    
    function setDescription(uint256 tokenId, string memory description) public {
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender, "Only the owner can set the description");
        canvases[tokenId].description = description;
    }
}
```

2. **2_deploy_infinity_canvas.js**:

```js
const InfinityCanvas = artifacts.require("InfinityCanvas");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(InfinityCanvas, { gas: 5000000 });
};
```

3. **truffle-config.js**:

```js
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*",
      gas: 5500000,
      gasPrice: 20000000000,
    },
  },

  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.21",
    }
  },

  db: {
    enabled: false
  }
};
```

#### Environment:

- Truffle version: v5.11.5
- Node version: v18.18.1
- Using Ganache CLI with the default settings

Any help or insights into why this is happening and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated!

#### Fixes Tried:

1. **Checking Constructor**: Verified that the `InfinityCanvas` contract does not have any parameters in its constructor that might not be provided during migration.
2. **Gas Limit**: Adjusted the gas limit in the migration script and `truffle-config.js` to ensure that the contract is not running out of gas during deployment.
3. **Checking Dependencies**: Made sure all dependencies and imported contracts (like those from OpenZeppelin) are of compatible versions.
4. **Manual Compilation**: Tried manually compiling the contract using `solc` to see if there were any issues not caught by Truffle.
5. **Migration Script**: Ensured that the migration script `2_deploy_infinity_canvas.js` doesn't have any inconsistencies or errors.
6. **Restarting Ganache**: Sometimes resetting Ganache can resolve nonce or other blockchain-related inconsistencies.
7. **Updating Truffle**: Ensured Truffle is up-to-date. Sometimes using the latest version of Truffle resolves certain deployment issues.
8. **Checking the Solidity Version**: Verified that the specified Solidity version in `truffle-config.js` matches the version in the contract file.
9. **Other Contracts**: Checked if there are any other contracts in the `contracts` directory that might be causing conflicts during migration.
10. **Following Question on StackOverflow**: ["Migrations" hit an invalid opcode while deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76377136/migrations-hit-an-invalid-opcode-while-deploying)

Unfortunately, none of the above steps resolved the issue. Its also possible though, that I did do something wrong when trying the above named fixes.